# How to fix [Simba][DriverOAuthSupport] Authentication failed: invalid_grant error?

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc, connector, simba

I'm using ODBC connector to connect to data in Google BigQuery which was working fine but is now giving this error.

[image]

Would be grateful if you could help advice how to fix this error.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Can you try with most recent version of the [Simba ODBC driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers#current_odbc_driver_releases_21231031) and let know if you are still facing the issue or not?

Comment: Let me try the latest version of Simba and get back to you

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT its still not working and its giving the same error

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker under the [BigQuery component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659).

Comment: Hello @PrajnaRaiT this is fixed now! It was an internal VPN issue

Comment: Hi @Mishal, I have posted the answer as Community wiki. So If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mishal, As you have mentioned in the comment that the issue was because of an internal VPN issue and the issue is now fixed.

There are four types of problems that tend to occur with VPN connections. These include:

1.The VPN connection being rejected.
2.The acceptance of an unauthorized connection.
3.The inability to reach locations that lie beyond the VPN server.
4.The inability to establish a tunnel.

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/fix-the-four-biggest-problems-with-vpn-connections/).